# Get account email of the current android and GooglePlay user account

Tags: android, android-billing, android-account

I have seen in other question how to get the device emails, but I need to get the email of the **current user**

I'm implementing in-App billing and need to know what is the email of the user for security check, so the email that I must get must be the same currently used for his GooglePlay account and this method doesn't sound very reliable for this purpose

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        ...
    }
}
```

A smartphone could have more accounts saved and I haven't understood how could I know what is the current account active between the various accounts in list.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but [here's something that looks promising](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address). Alternatively, in stead of automatically selecting a particular account, you could [invoke the `AccountPicker`](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html#AccountPicker) and let the user choose the desired account.

Comment: Thanks but since I need the account email for a security check I should check the email of current active account automatically without the user intervention.

Comment: @AndreaF: we have your same issue. Have you found a solution?